# More specific searching in sqlite3 for python

Tags: python, search, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 in python to quickly search through many values (it has been a lifesaver). The database has two entries per row: 'A' and 'B'. 'B' is a sequence of letters (seq).

I would like to count the number of times my search query of length l is like the first l+1 characters in 'B'.

My search code is currently:

```
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE seq LIKE ?', (t+'%',)):
```

which will check if my search query is present in 'B' but does not give me any further information.

I have tried to find the answer elsewhere, including stack overflow and sqlite3 documentation. Thank you.

Edit: Hello, it would be beneficial if those who are down voting my question can tell me why or direct me towards a resource that I have I may not have seen. Thank you.

Comment: So you want the number of rows that match?

Comment: Yes, the next line is i = i + 1 so it should count the values which 'match' to my search query. I would like to increment i only when the search query matches to the beginning of the value in 'B'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count rows, use an [aggregate](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) query:

```
c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_db WHERE seq LIKE ?", (t + '%',))
rows = c.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wish to count the values in the column 'B' which have the search query in the first l characters where l is the length of the search query. The method you've given gives all entries for B which contain the search query anywhere in the sequence. Is it possible to only search a specific part of the entry in B?

Comment: There is no B column. And LIKE would work like this only if the pattern were prefixed with `%`, too.

Comment: Thank you @CL! That's really helpful!